# Improve performance of an EXCEPT statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm doing a data comparison between a SQL Server database and a linked server database (Sybase ASA, Oracle or Ingres depending on which linked server specified).

I have a cursor that loops through all the tables in each database and does an except.

```
OPEN MY_Cursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM MY_Cursor INTO @TableName;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([LINKEDSERVER],'SELECT * FROM @TableName')
        EXCEPT
        SELECT * FROM @TableName

        IF @@ROWCOUNT <> 0
            BEGIN
                PRINT @TableName
            END

    FETCH NEXT FROM My_Cursor INTO @TableName
    END
```

This is doing a full table scan, and not returning results until all the rows have been compared. Since some of these tables have millions of rows, this is taking a very long time.

The execution plan indicates approx 95% of the performance problems are at the remote end. Unfortunately, I don't have permissions to create indexes or indexed views at the linked server database.

Is it possible to break the except statement and go onto the next iteration of the cursor as soon as any record that has a data difference is found?

Comment: Have you tried using `EXISTS`? That's assuming that you only want to detect a difference and not return any rows.

Comment: You are selecting `*` without any predicate. What index? What "performance"?

Comment: Really you have linked servers Sybase ASA, Oracle or Ingres with same table names, column names, datatypes, and in the same order.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM @TableName` should fail. It's impossible to parameterize identifiers without using dynamic sql.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using a loop instead of a CURSOR. Cursors are extremely inefficient and there aren't many ways to optimize a cursor because of how they work, You are also using full table scans and the reason it is so slow is because you have to do a full table scan for each record you come across because of how cursors work. I would look at trying to use a while loop and see if that helps you time. I would also try to add a where clause to the SQL Statement.